# Windows Phone 7 - Log output from a library assembly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a windows phone 7 library which needs to display log messages to developers.  Warning: I'm somewhat new to .Net.

It doesn't appear that System.Diagnostics.Trace is available on Windows Phone 7.  I also tried Console.Writeline but it doesn't seem to do anything.  So far the only thing that works is Debug.WriteLine() but when I build the library as a "Release" build, the logging goes away.

A) Has anyone found a way to log or trace from a "release" build of a Windows Phone 7 App?

B) Is there a way to build a release build (no symbols and optimized) that still has Debug output turned on.

Thanks,

Comment: So this morning I came up with an alternative solutions to this issue: Which  is too have our event-logging class raise an event on each log-message, then users of our library can register their own listener, where they can call Debug.WriteLine() or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to check out this recent release.

[Silverlight and WP7 Exception Handling and Logging building block](http://silverlightlogging.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Wow, thats pretty cool, thank you. Definitely worth an up vote, but in my case isn't the best solution.